# Need to validate if any one of the checkbox (gender) is selected in PHP. The following code doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, html

Please don't suggest to do checked = "checked" in HTML, because this validation is to be done in PHP is a requirement in my assignment.

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST["gender"])) {
$gender = $_POST["gender"];

if (($gender != "male") || ($gender != "female") || ($gender != "other"))  {
    $errMsg .= "<p>select a gender.</p>";
}

}
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>GENDER</legend>
<label>Select your Gender</label> <br/> <br/>
 <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"  />
 <label for="male">Male</label>
 <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" />
 <label for="female">Female</label>
 <input type="radio" name="gender" id="other" value="other" />
 <label for="other">Other</label>
```

Comment: Have you tried outputting the value of `$_POST["gender"]` to see it is giving the correct result?

Comment: You want `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: @Chaim Yea, it gives out the value.

Comment: @JonStirling tried that as well, doesn't work :/

Comment: Your validation is redundant in this case. If checkbox isn't checked, $_POST['gender'] will not be set... So, you don't need any conditions in this case... if(isset($_POST['gender'])) {//do what you want} else {//show error message - gender not set}

Comment: @nevermind Thanks, works! :)

Comment: P.S. If you want to dissallow user to change POST data, use Jon Stirling advice.

Answer (score 1):

The following code checks all available options for gender and by default set to "other". And I suppose, this code more simply than yours

```
$available = ['male', 'feemale', 'other'];

$gender = empty($_POST["gender"]) ? $_POST["gender"] : "other"; // "other by default";

if (!in_array($gender, $available)) {
    $errorMessage = 'Gender is incorrect';
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that is not all the html you have and its wrapped in a form with method = "post" if you do just try and echo out the variable to see if it works

Comment: It is. And just tried echoing $gender. It shows the value selected.